# How Can I verify the Data In Bulk Insert

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Say  i am inserting the data into the database using bulk insert  that is from asp.net to sol 2008.Now i Want to Validate the data How can i do that.Pls Help

Comment: What kind of validations would you like to do?

Comment: To check whether the data is Null,Data Already Exists and to verify Whether it is valid data

Comment: validation before insert or after insert? How exactly did you do the bulk insert? any code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for the most part your staging table's design should be such that it won't allow nulls where they should not be and the data types of the fields should be the types you expect. So say a field is a datetime then you won't be able to insert any data expect data that is a datetime type. Similarly if a field is defined to be an int then the data can't be a string type etc.

Try and use the feature/capabilities of the database to the extent possible by defining the correct datatypes for your fields. If any additional validations need to be done then you can run some stored procedure that does the other validations after import has finished.

Further, triggers on your destination table could help with ensuring valid data too.

For "data already exists" depending on what you want to do, you could use the MERGE statement to insert the data into the destination. The MERGE statement will allow you to ignore duplicates or update them (maybe some field's values have changed and you need to new values to be updated).

Comment: I would warn against relying on triggers during a bulk insert; they are entirely optional in this scenario

Comment: @Marc as you must know, the question is way too broad so I'm giving general suggestions/options not specifics.

Comment: fine, fine - but that doesn't make "triggers on the staging table" a reliable option...

Comment: @Marc I wasn't talking about using triggers in the staging table. Triggers are disabled during bulk inserts by default anyway. I was talking about triggers in the destination table.

Comment: @Marc, I see, I miss stated it in my answer

Answer (score 0):

I always bulk insert into a staging table (a table *representive* of the final home, but not used by the transactional system).

This:

- allows me to validate through TSQL (including checking any related data in other tables etc)
- ensures the final `INSERT` (into the real table) is fully logged (bulk inserts aren't, necessarily)
- ensures nobody reads the incomplete/unvalidated data
- prevents any blocks etc (to or from the live system)
- insulates from problems if the insert fails half way through

In your case, the first bullet is most paramount, but all the others matter too.

Also, since the data is coming from .NET, make sure you are using `SqlBulkCopy` if this truly is a bulk insert.

Comment: but does that answer the question of how to validate? :)

Comment: @shiv - yes, it does... once it is in a staging table you can use TSQL. Add whatever checks are required...